# I want text to do a sort of fadeIn and .slideDown at the same time when page loads

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

I want some text to slideDown and fadeIn at the same time when my page loads but I can't get anything to happen, or even get a fadeIn animation to work.

HTML:

```
<div id="animate" class="landing-text">
    <div class="landingText cantSee">
      <h1 class="newFont oColor textShadow">
      ELEVATEDMOVEMENT</h1>
      <h3 class="newFont oColor textShadow">
      Pushing the limits of movement</h3>
      <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="btn btnColor    
      btn-lg newFont">
      Shop</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cantSee
{
    opacity: 0.0;
}

.animateText
{
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity 0.5;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var div = document.getElementById("animate");
    div.className += " animateText";
});
```

I don't see why I can't get anything to happen when the page loads. It's probably a stupid mistake since I'm a beginner in web design but I would really appreciate help!

Comment: You have opacity 0 on the child div element but adding the opacity 1 to parent div element. There is no JQuery here, make up your mind and use css or jquery animate.

Comment: @NawedKhan The JQuery is what causes execution on page load

Comment: @NawedKhan please look at all the code first please, I have shown the Jquery in my post that is supposed to add the annimateText class on page load. That, of course, is not working and is my problem.

Comment: NawedKhan wasn't particularity wrong; if you're using jQuery only to listen for the window to load, there's not really much reason for you to be using it

Comment: @WBsimps yes you are using JQuery just to run a vanilla javascript function on document load. Not to animate. It is an unnecessary mix of Jquery, vanilla Javascript and css.

Comment: @NawedKhan well please help me fix it haha I just want it to start an animation when the page loads up. I already know it's wrong.

Comment: @WBsimps please look at Light's answer. It will do the trick. It is using the Jquery to do it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using jQuery, so you should make use of their methods; You can achieve this slide down and display with the input [`.slideDown()`](https://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) method

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('#animate').slideDown(1000);
});
```

```css
#animate {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="animate">
  <div class="cantSee">
    <h1>ELEVATEDMOVEMENT</h1>
    <h3>Pushing the limits of movement</h3>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Shop</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, I just had to remove the cant see class. I was sure I had tried this but I must have not had the right function to make it activate on page load. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone one else comes across this and wanted to know how to make both the fadeIn and slideDown work on load this is how you can achieve that effect:

HTML:

```
<div id="animate">
      <h1>Text</h1>
      <h3>More text</h3>
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#">Shop</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('#animate')
  .css('opacity', 0)
  .slideDown(1000)
  .animate(
    { opacity: 1 },
    { queue: false, duration: 1000 }
  )});
```

CSS:

```
#animate {
  display: none;
}
```